# c++ variable output unexpected

Tags: c++

Im writing a wordle game and am trying to get the output to work, but i have no clue as to what im doing wrong here. The basic version of the code is 5 letter words are taken from a word file and stored in an array, then a random word is picked from there to be the answer to the wordle. Then the user is prompted for input and once they input a word, it verifies the length, as well as if it is in the array of words. then another function takes the guessed word and compares it against the winning word and outputs the guessed word with colors to show what letters are in the right spot, like real wordle. The issue arises when i try to print everything out, i tried to use a while loop to ask for input but i couldnt get it to work so i decided to test it by making a function that asks for the input, then i called it six times, each time giving it a different variable to store the result in, then print out the first one on the first guess, the first and second on the second guess, and so on. But it only prints out the current guess. It might be something very obvious but i have spent so much time coding i have no idea. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const string CORRECT = "\033[7;32m";
const string CLOSE = "\033[7;33m";
const string INCORRECT = "\033[7;37m";
const string END = "\033[0m";

int verifyExists(string word, string verifyArr[2315]) {

  if (word.size() == 5)
    {

      for (int i = 0; i < 2315; i++)
        {

          if (word == verifyArr[i])
            {

              return 1;

            }
        }

      return 2;

    } else {

    return 3;

  }

}

string buildResult(string plyrGuess, string word)
{
  string result[5];
  string color;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if (plyrGuess[i] != word[i])
      {
        color = INCORRECT + plyrGuess[i] + END;
        result[i] = color;
      }

    if ((plyrGuess[i] != word[i]) && (plyrGuess[i] == word[0] || plyrGuess[i] == word[1] || plyrGuess[i] == w\
ord[2] || plyrGuess[i] == word[3] || plyrGuess[i] == word[4]))
      {
        color = CLOSE + plyrGuess[i] + END;
        result[i] = color;
      }

    if (plyrGuess[i] == word[i])
      {
        color = CORRECT + plyrGuess[i] + END;
        result[i] = color;
      }

  }

  string done;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      cout << result[i];
    }

  getline(cin, done);

  return done;
}

string askInput(string array[2315])
{
  string guessWord;

  cout << "What word would you like to guess?" << endl;

  getline(cin, guessWord);

  while (verifyExists(guessWord, array) == 2)
    {

      cout << "The word: " << guessWord << " is not in the word list" << endl;
      getline(cin, guessWord);

    }

  while (verifyExists(guessWord, array) == 3)
    {

      cout << "You must enter a word that is 5 letters in length: " << endl;
      getline(cin, guessWord);

    }

  return guessWord;

}

void playGame(string winWord, string arr[2315]) {

  cout << "Ok. I am thinking of a word with 5 letters." << endl;

  string guess1 = askInput(arr);
  string done1 = buildResult(guess1, winWord);
  cout << done1 << "\n" << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;

  string guess2 = askInput(arr);
  string done2 = buildResult(guess2, winWord);
  cout << done1 << endl;
  cout << done2 << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;


  string guess3 = askInput(arr);
  string done3 = buildResult(guess3, winWord);
  cout << done1 << endl;
  cout << done2 << endl;
  cout << done3 << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;

  string guess4 = askInput(arr);
  string done4 = buildResult(guess4, winWord);
  cout << done1 << endl;
  cout << done2 << endl;
  cout << done3 << endl;
  cout << done4 << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;

  string guess5 = askInput(arr);
  string done5 = buildResult(guess5, winWord);
  cout << done1 << endl;
  cout << done2 << endl;
  cout << done3 << endl;
  cout << done4 << endl;
  cout << "_____" << endl;

  string guess6 = askInput(arr);
  string done6 = buildResult(guess6, winWord);
  cout << done1 << endl;
  cout << done2 << endl;
  cout << done3 << endl;
  cout << done4 << endl;
  cout << done5 << endl;
  cout << done6 << endl;

}

int main() {

  string wordArray[2315];

  ifstream myfile ("proj1_data.txt");

  cout << "          Welcome to UMBC Wordle" << endl;

  if (myfile.is_open())
    {

      string word;

      int loop = 0;

      while (getline(myfile, word))
        {
          wordArray[loop++] = word;
        }

      cout << " " << endl;
      cout << "          Your file was imported!" << endl;
      cout << "          2315 Words imported" << endl;
      cout << " " << endl;

      myfile.close();

    }

  srand(time(0));
  string chosenWord = wordArray[rand() % 2315];

  playGame(chosenWord, wordArray);


  return 0;

}
```

I dont get any errors when i compile it so i know that nothings "wrong" with the code, the problem is in the playGame function, i included the whole code in case that helps

Comment: This needs a more [mre] which demonstrates only the one problem you want to discuss here. If you have a problem with outputting, then please remove reading in, storing, guessing, comparing. Show only how you try to output some hardcoded thing, exhibiting the same misbhaviour as in your full program. Creating that MRE should guide you in identifying the root cause of the problem which only becomes visible when you try to finally output.

Comment: *"I don't get any errors when i compile it so i know that nothings "wrong" with the code"* - that only means nothing is wrong with the *syntax*.  Mountains of code that compile to completion but are logically flawed are written every minute of every day. They are the dreams that *debuggers* were made for.

Comment: What is the idea behind `getline(cin, done);` in `buildResult`?

Comment: @NathanPierson could i just return result?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you _want_ to be returning from that function, but I really doubt that "ask for additional user input, then return whatever that is" is what you want. (Presumably all user input is supposed to be done via `askInput`.)

Comment: @yunnosch yeah i made a separate file to test in and it works there so im confused

Comment: Then you need to add more from the problematic code. And/or test the previously happening things more thoroughly. The MRE for this qustion should contain the part which makes visible and otherwise only the part which causes.